# google datastore - does it do lazy loading?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

if I have a Customer object with a list of orders, declared using the db.ReferenceProperty

after a while I may have huge amount of orders in there, if I pull the Customer object would I be in danger of pulling the complete set of orders?

Comment: First day working for Google?

Comment: @Silmarl89 - and your point is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, db.ReferenceProperty fields are loaded lazily.  From [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty):

> ReferenceProperty automatically references and dereferences model instances as property values: A model instance can be assigned to a ReferenceProperty directly, and its key will be used. The ReferenceProperty value can be used as if it were a model instance, and **the datastore entity will be fetched and the model instance created when it is first used in this way. Untouched reference properties do not query for unneeded data.**

So, for example:

```
# Any reference properties not loaded yet
customer = Customer.get_by_id(1)
print customer.name
print customer.address

# Assuming customer.order is a ReferenceProperty, now is when it
# would be loaded from the datastore.
print customer.order.created_at
```

Comment: May be of interest: The back-reference created by `ReferenceProperty` properties are actually `Query` instances, so you can also query for a sub-set of entities that reference the parent entity: `customer.orders.filter('company', 'ACME').order('-created').fetch(10)`

Comment: Good point about the automagically-created queries at the other end of ReferenceProperty fields.